# Different Postgres schemes with different models in Python alembic

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, serverless-framework, alembic

I am new to using SQLAlchemy and Alembic and I’m trying to work with different models and schemas in a Postgres database. These schemas represent different system domains and the idea is to unify database models and migrations into a single project. My question is whether it is possible to keep migrations from the database with a single instance of alembic? I would appreciate some approach or suggestion on how to implement this.